# PHP Select a survey from array

Tags: php

I'm a new at PHP and working on my 3rd assignment. I have a page that displays 3 radio buttons, each associated with a different survey. The user clicks on a survey and submits to display the questions. I cannot figure out why only the first set of survey questions will display regardless of which radio button they select. I would greatly appreciate help.

```html
<?php
session_start();
require_once ('arrays.php');

// The isset() function is used to check whether a variable is set or not.
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) || $_SESSION['logged_in'] == false) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

$isPostBack = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submitButton') !== NULL;
if ($isPostBack) {
    // This is what happens if there is a postback.
    $choose_survey = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'choose_survey', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
    if ($choose_survey !== NULL) {
        // Check the value of $choose_survey and then set 'survey' accordingly, e.g.
        if ($choose_survey == "The Shire")
            $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey0;
        else if ($choose_survey == "Minas Tirith")
            $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey1;
        else if ($choose_survey == "Rivendell")
            $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey2;
        // A survey is selected so this is what happens.
        // these are the survey questions
        // this will contain the answers
        $_SESSION['answers'] = array();
        // this is the question number
        $_SESSION['number'] = 1;
    } else {
        // A survey is not selected because it was already chosen.
        // get the value from the radio button.
        $answer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'answer', FILTER_DEFAULT);
        $question_key = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'question_key', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
        // this will be used later to display the answers/results
        $_SESSION['answers'][$question_key] = $answer;
        // This is adding 1 to the question number.
        $_SESSION['numbers'] += 1;
        unset($_SESSION['survey'][$question_key]);
    }
} else {
    // This is what happens if there is no postback.

    // add code that records which survey they selected for the results page
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>

<form id="survey" name="survey" method="post" action="survey.php">
    <?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION['survey'])):
        echo '<p>Please choose a survey</p>';

        foreach ($surveys as $key => $value) {
            $surveyButton = <<<HEREDOC
    <label for = "$key">$value</label>
    <input type="radio" name="choose_survey" id="$key" value="$key"><br>
HEREDOC;
            echo $surveyButton;
        }
    else: ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h1 class="survey-header">Please respond to each survey statement</h1>
            <?php
            $key = array_key_first($_SESSION['survey']);
            $value = $_SESSION['survey'][$key];
            $surveyQuestions = <<<HEREDOC
            <input type="hidden" name="question_key" value="$key">
    <label class="statement"> $value </label>
        <ul class='likert'>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="$key" name="answer" value="strong_agree">
                <label>Strongly agree</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="$key" name="answer" value="agree">
                <label>Agree</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="$key" name="answer" value="neutral">
                <label>Neutral</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="$key" name="answer" value="disagree">
                <label>Disagree</label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" id="$key" name="answer" value="strong_disagree">
                <label>Strongly disagree</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
HEREDOC;
            echo $surveyQuestions;
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>



**And my arrays.php file contains the following code:** 



<?php
$surveys = array("The Shire", "Minas Tirith", "Rivendell");

$survey0 = array(
    'Staying in the Shire was the best part of my vacation.',
    'The food served at The Green Dragon tavern was excellent.',
    'The party to celebrate Bilbo\'s birthday was my favorite event.',
    'Gandalf\'s firework show was unforgettable experience',
    'The weather during my visit was perfect.',
    'The bed in Bilbo\'s home was very comfortable.',
    'I enjoyed visiting The Green Dragon during my stay. ',
    'I will return to the Shire for another visit in the future.',
    'I would have liked my stay at the Shire to be longer.',
    'Visiting the Shire has been one of the greatest experiences of my life.'
);


    $survey1 = array (
        'Staying in Minas Tirith was the best part of my vacation. ',
        'The view at the top of Minas Tirith was the highlight of my stay.',
        'Dining with the king of Minas Tirith was the highlight of my stay. ',
        'The meals served in the great hall was some of the best I\'ve ever had.',
        'The weather during my stay at Minas Tirith was perfect.',
        'The bed in my castle suite was very comfortable.',
        'I enjoyed the many royal parties in the royal courtyard.',
        'I will return to Minas Tirith for another visit in the future.',
        'I would have liked my stay at Minas Tirith be be longer.',
        'Visiting Minis Tirith as been one of the greatest experiences of my life.'
    );

    $survey2 = array (
        'Staying in Rivendell was the best part of my vacation.',
        'Experiencing the many waterfalls was the highlight of my stay in Rivendell.',
        'Attending the annual celebration with the elves in Rivendell was the highlight of my vacation.',
        'The meals served in Rivendell\'s great hall was some of the best I\'ve ever had.',
        'The weather during my visit in Rivendell was perfect.',
        'The bed in my suite at Rivendell was very comfortable.',
        'I enjoyed exploring the many beautiful gardens in Rivendell.',
        'I will return to Rivendell for another visit in the future.',
        'I would have liked my stay in Rivendell to be longer.',
        'Visiting Rivendell has been one of the greatest experiences of my life.'
    );

?>
```

Comment: Take a look at the superglobal variables, [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php). Print out the results and there you will see what values you are passing into `survey.php` from the form on submit.

Comment: Here ,  `$_SESSION['survey'] = $survey0;` you are assigning first survey question  always ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI Its difficult to tell whats going on, it helps us to help you if you create a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** so we can see where the problem is.

It doesn't look like you are checking what survey was selected - you just set the survey to `$survey0` regardless.

What you are doing:

```
$choose_survey = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'choose_survey', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
if ($choose_survey !== NULL) {
    // if ANY survey was selected, then set 'survey' to $survey0
    $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey0;

    [etc...]
```

You need to check the value of `$choose_survey` and use it to decide which survey to use, e.g.

```
$choose_survey = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'choose_survey', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
if ($choose_survey !== NULL) {
    // Check the value of $choose_survey and then set 'survey' accordingly, e.g.
    if ($choose_survey == "The Shire")
        $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey0;
    else if ($choose_survey == "Minas Tirith")
        $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey1;
    else if ($choose_survey == "Rivendell")
        $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey2;
    [etc...]
```

**UPDATE:**

The radio buttons values are the array indexes so (1)validate the posted data as as INT instead of a FLOAT and (2)change the if statements to check for 0,1 and 2:

```
// UPDATE 1: Save the posted value as an integer instead of a float:
$choose_survey = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'choose_survey', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
if ($choose_survey !== NULL) {

    // TEST THE VALUE: print out the saved value to see if its what you expect
    echo "<p>Saved value for choose survey = $choose_survey</p>";

    //Check the value of $choose_survey and then set 'survey' accordingly
    // UPDATE 2: the values are the array index so change the if statements :
    if ($choose_survey == 0)
        $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey0;
    else if ($choose_survey == 1)
        $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey1;
    else if ($choose_survey == 2)
        $_SESSION['survey'] = $survey2;

    // At this point, 'survey' should have the correct value...

    [etc...]
```

Tip: Printing out the variables along the way can help you see where the problem is happening.

Comment: Thank you. That certainly makes sense. I'm not able to make it work though. I will edit my post above to include this.  Maybe there is another mistake I need to correct.

Comment: @Vienne There could well be other errors too, but you also forgot to remove the line that sets the 'survey' to `$survey0`, so you are resetting it again. See my updated answer

Comment: I'm embarrassed that I forgot to delete that line. Thank you for pointing it out.  The first survey is the only one now that will display.  If the 2nd and 3rd radio buttons are chosen, nothing happens. I will edit my above code to show and continue looking for mistakes

Comment: @Vienne Have you checked the value of choose_survey thats posted and what gets saved to the '$choose_survey' variable? You're using `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT` but is choose_survey not a string? I suggest printing out the values at each step to try figure out at what point the problem is happening. e.g. use `print_r($_POST);` at the start of the php file to see what values are submitted.

Comment: I meant to apologize for including so much code in my question.  Unfortunately, being so new at PHP and still struggling to understand, I'm not confident that I know where my problem lies. I simply don't know what needs to be shared and what doesn't. This is why I pointed at in the beginning that this is a new language for me.  I'm trying very hard to get a better understanding of the logic involved.

Comment: That is something I am unfamiliar with.   Thank you for the suggestion and explanation.  I will do that now.

Comment: This was the result ... Array ( [choose_survey] => 1 [submitButton] => Submit )

Comment: @Vienne I've updated my update with the changes. I assumed the radio button value was the string, instead its the array index. You just need to change the `if ($choose_survey == XXX)` lines to check for 0, 1 and 2 instead of "The Shire" etc. Then add a line to print out the value of the `$choose_survey` variable to make sure its being saved correctly (I think `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT` will change it to a decimal which won't work either).

Comment: (heavy sigh of relief) ... That did it. It's working perfectly.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help and for your patience with my lack of understanding.  I often feel too intimidated to post questions. Your help is so appreciated.

Comment: @Vienne Glad you got sorted! Printing out the variables is a simple but effective way of trying to track down where the problem could be. Take a look through [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) too, it might help you identify where the problem is in future. And don't be afraid to post... as long as you show that you have made a decent attempt at figuring out the problem, people are more than willing to help. We were all newbies at some point! But the more you can narrow it down, the easier it is for us too :)

Comment: I have looked over the page you shared with me. Thank you for that.  And, again, for your help. I can't believe I'm back in college again at age 49. It would be far more of a challenge without sites like stackoverflow, that offer help.  I'm hoping I can get through the remainder of this assignment on my own but I may end up back tomorrow with another question/problem. :)